# Clarification on the concept of linear functional

Tags: nonparametric

Sorry if this question appears a bit basic, I'm struggling with the concept of linear functional.

For example, [lectures notes from David Hunter](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/fall2002/lectures/ln14.pdf) define them as follows:

[image]

However, it appears to me that I can define $$\phi(x) = (x-\mu)^2$$ which is the same as defining $$T(F) = VAR(F) $$ but then the law expressed above would translate into $$VAR(\alpha F_1 + (1-\alpha)F_2) = \alpha VAR(F_1) + (1-\alpha)VAR(F_2)$$

Which obviously is NOT correct.

Could you please help me identify the flaw in my reasoning above? Thanks!

Comment: Re your penultimate comment: the equation obviously *is* correct.  Perhaps you are confusing distribution functions with random variables?

Comment: Oh! Yes, I'm exactly confusing RV and distribution function! Multiplying a distribution function is not the same as multiplying a RV, right, I get it now. 
Thanks a lot!